# Why don't we follow the same process creating customTableViewCell with xib as creating customView with xib?

Tags: ios, swift

**When we are creating customView, we set the view File's owner to custom class and we instantiate it with initWithFrame or initWithCode.**

When we are creating customUITableViewCell, we set the view's class to custom class, instead File's owner's. And then register all the nibs so on.
İn this way, we always need to register the xibs to UIViewController and

`let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)`so on.

What I find is that I don't want to register nibs all the time where I want to use customUITableViewCell. So I want to initialize xib inside my customUITableCell like the same process of creating customUIView. And I succeed. Here are the steps.

**My question is what is the preferred way of creating customUITableCell?**
**With this method there is no need to register nibs and we can call customCell where we want to without loading/registering nib.**

1. Set the view's File's Owner of xib to customUITableCell class. Not the view's class set to customClass, just File's Owner.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwAyK.png)

2. My custom class called myView: UITableViewCell

   ```
   import UIKit

   class myView: UITableViewCell {

       var subView: UIView!


       required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
           super.init(coder: aDecoder)
           initSubviews()
       }

       override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
           super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

           initSubviews()
       }

       func initSubviews(){
           subView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! UIView

           subView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing(rawValue:  UIViewAutoresizing.RawValue(UInt8(UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleWidth.rawValue) |  UInt8(UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleHeight.rawValue)))
           self.addSubview(subView)

       }
   }
   ```
3. İnside UIVivController, I did't register nibs and use

`let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)`

Instead, I did this.

let cell = myView(style: .default , reuseIdentifier: "TableViewCell")

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {



var tableStyle: UITableView = UITableView()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            tableStyle.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
            tableStyle.delegate = self
            tableStyle.dataSource = self
            view.addSubview(tableStyle)
        }


        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
            return 100.00
        }
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return 1        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

           let cell = myView(style: .default , reuseIdentifier: "TableViewCell")

            return cell
        }
    }
```

4. Here is the result.

[Image 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hasE.png)

THANKS FOR YOUR TIME!!!

Comment: Just a tip: If you have code, post the code. Don't post a screenshot of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach means every single time the `UITableView` requests a new cell, you're creating a brand new cell from scratch. That it means it has to:

1. find the nib
2. load the nib
3. parse it to find the views
4. make the views
5. update the cell

This is no better than having a long scroll view with custom views for it's entire length.

The beauty of `UITableView` is it optimizes much of this process and re-uses cells, massively cutting down the performance cost of having more cells than fit on your screen. **With the traditional (correct) approach, steps 1-4 only have to happen once**.

To expand on the differences in the xib:

When creating a cell with `UITableView`, you only give it the nib, and the system looks in the nib to find a `UITableViewCell`. A simple `UIView` will not work.

You actually *can* subclass the `UIView` in your `xib` with your custom class. It just happens that the norm is to use `fileOwner`, largely because that's the norm when using nibs with `UIViewControllers` as was required in the pre-storyboard era

Comment: Thank you. I understand the differences now.

Answer (score 0):

An addition to the accepted answer:

If your only problem with the "classic" approach is that you need to register the nib and call `dequeueReusableCell`, you can simplify the calls with a nice protocol extension as discussed in [this article](https://medium.com/bleeding-edge/nicer-reuse-identifiers-with-protocols-in-swift-97d18de1b2df):

```
protocol ReuseIdentifying {

    static var reuseIdentifier: String { get }

}

extension ReuseIdentifying {

    static var reuseIdentifier: String {
        return String(describing: Self.self)
    }

}

extension UITableViewCell: ReuseIdentifying {}
```

To register you just call

```
self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: MyTableViewCell.reuseIdentifier, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: MyTableViewCell. reuseIdentifier)
```

And to create it you call

```
let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: MyTableViewCell. reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
```

(Of course this only works if class, xib and reuse identifier all have the same name)

Comment: Thank you. Actually I have no problem with classical approach. I just confused with creating custom UIView. Because we set file's owner to class there. Not view's class to custom class. But here we set view's class to custom class and don't initiate with initWithCoder or initSomething here too. (here means classical approach)

Comment: A nice extension to this extension is to use a small library called [Reusable](https://github.com/AliSoftware/Reusable).

Comment: Interesting, thank you for the link. I try to use as few frameworks as possible, especially if i can solve a problem with just a few lines if code. But I will give it a try.